# XSLT matching most specific subtype

Tags: xslt, xsd, saxon

Suppose I have a type hierarchy such that `RetentionContest` **is-a** `BallotMeasureContest` **is-a** `Contest` (in my XSD). Then I have several XSLT templates such as

```xml
<xsl:template name="cdf:BallotMeasureContest" match="element(*, cdf:BallotMeasureContest)">
```

and

```xml
<xsl:template name="cdf:RetentionContest" match="element(*, cdf:RetentionContest)">
```

Assuming I have an input of `@xsi:type = "cdf:RentionContest"` and I am using a Schema-aware processor, which template gets called? How can I make sure the template for the most specific subtype gets called? (NB: I tried priority without much success). Altova and Saxon-EE seem to just call the last applicable one.

repro_delete.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<n1:ElectionReport xmlns:n1="http://itl.nist.gov/ns/voting/1500-100/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://itl.nist.gov/ns/voting/1500-100/v2 repro_delete.xsd">
    <n1:Election>
        <n1:Contest xsi:type="n1:RetentionContest" ObjectId="rc-123">
            <n1:CandidateId>rc-123</n1:CandidateId>
        </n1:Contest>
    </n1:Election>
</n1:ElectionReport>
```

repro_delete.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cdf="http://itl.nist.gov/ns/voting/1500-100/v2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors" exclude-result-prefixes="array cdf fn map math xhtml err xs xsi" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:import-schema namespace="http://itl.nist.gov/ns/voting/1500-100/v2" schema-location="repro_delete.xsd"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="cdf:C" match="element(*, cdf:Contest)">
Contest
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="cdf:RC" match="element(*, cdf:RetentionContest)">
Retention
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="cdf:BMC" match="element(*, cdf:BallotMeasureContest)">
Ballot Measure Contest
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

repro_delete.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://itl.nist.gov/ns/voting/1500-100/v2"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://itl.nist.gov/ns/voting/1500-100/v2" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    version="2.0.3">
    <xsd:element name="ElectionReport" type="ElectionReport"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="BallotMeasureContest">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Contest">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="FullText" type="InternationalizedText" minOccurs="0"
                    > </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="Contest" abstract="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="SubUnitsReported" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"> </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="TotalSubUnits" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"> </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="ObjectId" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="Election">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Contest" type="Contest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            > </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="ElectionReport">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Election" type="Election" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            > </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="InternationalizedText">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Text" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="Label" type="xsd:string"> </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="RetentionContest">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="BallotMeasureContest">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="CandidateId" type="xsd:IDREF"> </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I would think that `match="element(*, cdf:BallotMeasureContest)"` and `match="element(*, cdf:RetentionContest)"` have the same default priority `0`. I am not sure what you are asking for with "which template gets called" as obvious with `xsl:call-template` (template "calling") the name attribute determines that. For apply-templates and template matching I would think that the same default priority means that the result depends on `xsl:mode on-multiple-match` e.g. if you set `last` or `fail`. I don't see why priorities wouldn't work.

Comment: So I can't reproduce the issue with the MRE I came up with. I will have to revisit the original code to see if something more nuanced is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for allocating a default priority to different XSLT patterns are somewhat crude; they don't always have the effect that if pattern P matches a subset of the nodes matched by pattern Q, then P is chosen in preference to Q. In particular, all patterns of the form `element(*, T)` have the same default priority regardless of the schema type.

You will need to handle this by allocating explicit priorities using the `priority` attribute.