# Order of templates in a stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have noticed an odd behavior of templates when I change their order, which in my opinion should not be the case:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <a>
  <b>
   <c>1</c>
   <c>2</c>
   <c>3</c>
  </b>
 </a>
 <a>
  <b>
   <c>4</c>
   <c>5</c>
   <c>6</c>
  </b>
 </a>
</root>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b/c">higher priority</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="b/*">lower priority</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

6 x lower priority
I think it should be 6xhigher priority, because b/c is more precise then b/*

When I change the order of the templates, I get the following output:

XSL:

````
....
    <xsl:template match="b/*">lower priority</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="b/c">higher priority</xsl:template>
.....
```

6 x higher priority

Why is that?

Tested on:

chrome
https://xslttest.appspot.com/
https://linangdata.com/xslt-tester/
http://xsltransform.net/

On an older Version of Chrome this works as expected.
````

Comment: WRT *"b/c is more precise then b/*", see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75631490/3016153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your templates have the same priority of 0.5.

In this situation the processor must either signal an error, or choose the template that occurs last in the stylesheet.

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#conflict

Comment: I think the template with the match="b/*" should have priority -0.25 and the template with the match="b/c" should have 0.5. Why do you think they have both priority 0.5?

Comment: Because they do. A priority of -0.25 is assigned to a pattern of `namespace::*`. That's not what you have.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought always, the preciser the xpath in the match the higher the priority, like in CSS. But this is wrong.

Comment: @Mario: Please accept this answer by clicking on the check box beneath the answer score.  Thanks.